# How can a delayed job be made dependent on another job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

With Rails 3.2, is it possible to setup a delayed job so that it has a dependency on another delayed job, such that it will not run until the other job has finished (either successfully or not)? I have a class that spins off a large number of delayed jobs that need to be run sequentially to prevent a race condition. For performance reasons it is not possible to wait for each job to complete synchronously, though if it's not possible to put dependencies on jobs I could create a delayed job that runs each job in turn and waits for it to complete.

Comment: Any updates. How did you solve this issue? Can you update your answer here

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the author of [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/delayed_job/Yp7Wx9_pWls):

I would create a model to keep track of which steps are finished and not enqueue the next step until the previous ones are finished.